# How do I call an Activity within a TabHost?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have a fragment and within that Fragment I have a button that can called another Activity

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_fragment, container, false);

  Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherPage.class);
          startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Now this works fine.

But however, now I want to do the Same thing but within a **TabHost** that I created in this Fragment.

So how do I call `getActivity()` within my Tab?

I tried doing:

```
public class tab_two_graph extends AppCompatActivity {

  View v;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_two_graph);

     Intent intent = getParent().getIntent();
     v = intent.getParcelableExtra("view");

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(v.getActivity(), Alert_main_page.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

  }
```

But it just throws errors.

Comment: View v;  --- try to do it "public final".
And give errors content (Runtime or Сompiler does not accept the syntax?)

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add more information to the answers here.

You do not have to pass an Activity to start another activity. You need to pass a context, which can be accessed by using `tab_two_graph.this`. Which is why the following works :

```
startActivity(new Intent(tab_two_graph.this, Alert_main_page.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it with the current activity, not your View. So you can call it by using:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(tab_two_graph.this, Alert_main_page.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Please read at [Starting Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)
.

Answer (score 1):

public class tab_two_graph extends "AppCompatActivity" <<<<<

try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(tab_two_graph.this, Alert_main_page.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(((<YourActivityName>) getActivity()), AnotherPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
```